# Shooting inaccurate bullets due to x,y stepping

Tags: java

when shooting (slow) bullets in my Java game, they move at incorrect angles, however when sped up they become more and more accurate.

My x, y, speed and directions are all int, however I've tried converting to floats for more accuracy but I'm still having the same error. I believe it's happening because the lowest movement steps I can have are in integers like (+2x and +1y a step and not +1.7x and +0.88y - and I can't be on 0.5 of a pixel)

How do I 'microstep' the bullets to shoot them on the correct angle?
The only other solution I can think of to shoot them at the correct angle is to calculate the end collision point and step towards that point.

Desired behavior is for bullets to shoot at the correct angle (player to mouse) rather then at 'off' angles based on the bullets speed.

```
public class Bullet extends GameObject
{
private int x;
private int y;
private int speed = 2;
private int direction;
private int length = 70;

public Bullet(int x, int y, int direction)
    {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.direction = direction; //Set the direction.
    }

public void update(Game game, GameController gc, float dt)
    {
    x += GameController.lengthdir_x(speed, direction);
    y += GameController.lengthdir_y(speed, direction);
    }

public void render(Game game, Renderer r)
    {
    //Draw the bullet with the tail behind it.
    r.drawLine(x, y, x + GameController.lengthdir_x(length, direction - 180), y + GameController.lengthdir_y(length, direction - 180), color);

    r.drawText("Dir: " + direction, x + 50, y + 20, 0xff0077ff); //Draws the players angle.
    }
}
```

Lengthdir Code: (The angle calculates correctly as I can draw a line between two points perfectly, just when I add movement it messes up)

```
    public static int lengthdir_x(int len, int dir)
    {
    return (int) (len * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(dir - 90)));
    }

public static int lengthdir_y(int len, int dir)
    {
    return (int) (len * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dir - 90)));
    }
```

I've also tried doubles for variables: https://pastebin.com/fbrF17bD

Example: http://puu.sh/x9OnN/be4e3f2c80.png
The long blue line is from the player to the mouse, the yellow lines are bullets which are at the correct angle it was shot at - but not travelling the correct direction which should be exactly on the blue line. This was at a bullet speed of 2 - if the bullets are at a speed of 20, they are much closer to the blue line as per the next img: http://puu.sh/x9OwY/a54f201c91.png

Comment: can you show `GameController.lengthdir_x(speed, direction);` and `GameController.lengthdir_y(speed, direction);`?

Comment: Never calculate with `int`, even if you think that pixels are int anyway. This just introduces inaccuracies. Either take `double` or `BigDecimal` and only convert to `int` when everything has been calculated and you want to draw the object/shape.

Comment: Added the lengthdir codes, i'll keep it in double Tom from now on to keep it simple.

Comment: @Tom: I think that very much depends on the *type* of computation. Using BigDecimals for computations on coordinates sounds like big performance overkill to me.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: I just put some numbers into your `lengthdir_x` function and it gave me wrong results: if your direction is 90° (straight up) you will get `len` as result for x, where you should get 0, so I would suggest you check your direction calculations...

Comment: I've triple checked those calculations and they work well when drawing lines around the player, they even work for the bullets to a degree. The faster the bullet the more accurate the shot - it's just I need it accurate at low speeds.

Comment: @FluidicIce it will give you additional speed for x for direction of 90°, it doesn't make any sense. If it work for other things, maybe you need to create a new function to calculate your speed

Comment: Without the - 90 the bullets shoot at right angles incorrectly to the direction they should be going in. That was just to make the 0 angle at the top of the screen and not right. I'll keep fiddling with new speed functions though.

Comment: @FluidicIce can you pls update your code to the current state with new speed functions?

Comment: When I made changes I always revert them back to this base code if it doesn't work - so I'm still running the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your Problem: you use Integer-cast on the calculation result, that means you just remove everything after `.`, so if you get 1.9 as result you will return 1 as length. If you increase `speed` this error will be reduced, thats why you get better result for higher `speed`. You need to round your result before you return it. On the other hand you should really change to double. In the code you shown where you use double you didn't changed it in length-function, thats why you don't get better result using double. So your code should look like this:

```
public static double lengthdir_x(int len, int dir)
{
    //don't cast here to int!!!!
    return len * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(dir - 90));
}


public class Bullet extends GameObject
{
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private int speed = 2;
    private int direction;
    private int length = 70;

    public Bullet(double x, double y, int direction)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.direction = direction; //Set the direction.
    }

    public void update(Game game, GameController gc, float dt)
    {
        x += GameController.lengthdir_x(speed, direction);
        y += GameController.lengthdir_y(speed, direction);
    }

    public void render(Game game, Renderer r)
    {
        //Draw the bullet with the tail behind it.
        r.drawLine((int)Math.round(x), (int)Math.round(y), x + GameController.lengthdir_x(length, direction - 180), y + GameController.lengthdir_y(length, direction - 180), color);

        r.drawText("Dir: " + direction, (int)x + 50, (int)y + 20, 0xff0077ff); //Draws the players angle.
    }
}
```

Maybe you will need to convert something to int or double somewhere, but make sure `lengthdir` returns `double` as result or at least `(int)Math.round(...)`

Comment: I'll test it when I'm back home - I believe I did remove the (int) casts from lengthdir when I tested the doubles, but i'll have another go and fiddle with it some more.

Comment: I've got it working with some minor adjustments to your addition. Removing the (int) casts were only 1/3 of the solution with the others being changing the x,y ints to doubles and the directions to doubles as well. Although it's still confusing how position can be in floats as the player can't be on x= 53.3 pixels.

Comment: you should definitely stick with `double`, because every time you cast to `int` and add it to `x`/`y` you will accumulate additional error, even if you use `Math.round(...)`. You shouldn't worry about pixels, in some systems(especially on mobile devices) you often have high pixel density and your draw-function often work with dip(Density-independent-pixel), where you actually can have a real pixel at 53.3